# Bluetooth adapter lost after updating ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, laptop, bluetooth, acer

My laptop is an acer V13 V3-371-570S

When booting on livecd and after install, my internal bluetooth adapter is recognized and fully working.

After updating my system, my bluetooth adapter has gone,

```
bluetooth service● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since mar. 2015-09-01 21:54:53 CEST; 1h 30min left
 Main PID: 898 (bluetoothd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─898 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n
```

sept. 01 21:54:53 nb-acer bluetoothd[898]: bluetoothd[898]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
sept. 01 21:54:53 nb-acer bluetoothd[898]: bluetoothd[898]: Failed to init proximity plugin
sept. 01 21:54:53 nb-acer bluetoothd[898]: bluetoothd[898]: Failed to init time plugin
sept. 01 21:54:53 nb-acer bluetoothd[898]: bluetoothd[898]: Failed to init alert plugin
sept. 01 21:54:53 nb-acer bluetoothd[898]: bluetoothd[898]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
sept. 01 21:54:53 nb-acer systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
sept. 01 21:54:53 nb-acer bluetoothd[898]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
sept. 01 21:54:53 nb-acer bluetoothd[898]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
sept. 01 21:54:53 nb-acer bluetoothd[898]: bluetoothd[898]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
sept. 01 21:54:53 nb-acer bluetoothd[898]: bluetoothd[898]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized

Any idea ?

Result of the command :

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0918]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e07d]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0489:e076 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
bluetooth             491520  9 bnep,ath3k,btusb
[    6.052372] usb 3-1.5: Direct firmware load for ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020100.dfu failed with error -2
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the results from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware`

Answer (score 0):

The firmware file might have changed names, Pilot6 has a PPA with the firmware file

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Reboot

Comment: Sorry for the delay. PPA added, linux-formware package installed. Still doesn't work. Same problem on Fedora 22 (bluetooth ok after install, adapter not recognized after system update).

Comment: What kernel version? `uname -a`